# How to import a py module from a sub-dir (which's name starts with digits) of parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Because of the possibly confusing title of the question, I would like to clarify my question

Imagine the following directory structre:

- parent-dir

  - 01_sub-dir

    - file01.py
  - 02_sub-dir

    - file02.py

Being in file02.py I want to import a class located in file01.py by using relative imports.

I tried importing the class "my_class" from 01_subdir as follows:
`from ..01_subdir.file01 import my_class`

with this I keep getting following Error:

`SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal` <-- refering to the 01_ of the first sub directory

The directory structure can't be changed.

Sadly I cant share the source code.

Comment: `01_sub-dir` is not a legal [identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) according to the Python grammar spec, so there is no way you can use it as part of an import statement.

Answer (score 0):

all paths in the project are relative to the root directory.
Try simply:

```
from 01_subdir.file01 import my_class
```

Comment: but you should run file02 from the root directory as
"python3 02_subdir/file02.py"